# Размещение элементов в контейнере

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Ситуация: есть контейнер, ширина 1140px. В нем есть 2 картинки с размером 555/555px, и у первой margin-right: 30px;, у второй - отсутствует. При этом вторая картинка переносится на второю строку, в одной не помещается, влезает только при margin-right: 26px. В чем может быть проблема? как убрать эти фантомные отступы, которые мешают им влезть в 1 строку? Если при таких величинах ширина и должна быть как раз те 1140px. Заранее благодарен

Comment: border небось по 1px ?

Comment: border не указан, даже дополнительно прописывал none для border-а, не помогает(

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так.

```css
div {
  width: 1140px;
  font-size: 0;
}
img {
  width: 555px;
  height: 200px;
}
img:first-child {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.humanesociety.org/sites/default/files/styles/1240x698/public/2018/08/kitten-440379.jpg?h=c8d00152&itok=1fdekAh2" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/67/197567-131-1645A26E/Scottish-fold-cat-feline.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Почитать об этом можно [тут](https://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html). Ниже приведён немного отредактированный кусок из статьи.

Причина фантомных отступов в том, что браузер создаёт пустой текстовый узел (эта тема вроде как связана с JavaScript'ом и DOM, но можно интуитивно понять), который, по сути, может являться переводом строки, пробелом или, например, табом. Все и эти перечисленные вещи превращаются в один единственный пробел и описывается следующей сущностью: `&#x0020;`. Следует учитывать, что, так как пробел — это обычный символ, то, соответственно, и изменяться этот символ будет в зависимости от размера или семейства шрифта, т.е, по сути, вести себя также, как и обычная буква в строке. Так как это текстовый узел, при добавлении родителю наследуемого свойства font-size со значением 0, он перестаёт отображаться.

Comment: насколько следует из вопроса, то так и сделано.

Comment: Не понимаю с чего вы так решили. Там не написано, что выставлен font-size.

Comment: уже заметил. Не сочтите за труд писать пояснения к своим ответам, а не только код кидать. Это несколько отличает плохой ответ от хорошего. Тем не менее, если  у автор нет пробелов в верстке, то сие решение не поможет ведь?

Comment: Немного сложно формулировать некоторые вещи, поэтому я прикрепил статью. Насколько я знаю, фантомных отступов быть в принципе не должно, если пробелов/переносов строки нет.

Comment: Пробелов в верстке изначально не было, код был так же написан как в ответе тут. Помогла информация со статьи, а именно отрицательный margin. font-size 0 проблему так же изначально не решил. Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @Daniel в ответе тут как раз и есть пробелы между img. они на разных строках написаны и отступы имеются. отрицательный марджин это плохое решение, т.к. значение завивит от шрифта .

Comment: @egbro правила публикации ответов прямо указывают на то, что лучше часть информации скопировать в ответ, а не просто ссылаться на статью, т.к. статья сегодня есть, а завтра нет. Все конечно не надо. но хотя бы один-два абзаца самого важного будут уместны.

Comment: @teran ясно, буду иметь ввиду. Добавил пояснение к ответу, чтобы он соответствовал.